# Running terminal command over SSH with PHP return different version?

Tags: php, ssh, command-line, command

I have my app published in a server and

I ssh into the machine, cd into the home directory and run

`php -v` then I got `PHP 7.4.5 (cli) (built: Apr 18 2020 01:11:34) ( NTS )`

If I run the same command over SSH

`ssh MY_USER@SERVER_IP "php -v"` then I got `PHP 5.6.22-2 (cli)`

I'm trying to trigger a `composer install` remotely but it fails because of 
the php version.

I'd like to run the command with php 7.4 of course.

Any tips?

Thanks

Ps. If I run 'whoami' I get the same user.

Comment: you have multiple php cli version installed. You can get the php's location by using whereis php command

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed there's several php cli installed.

Comment: @DavidHlavati, would you know how I'm supposed to run the correct php version? :)

Comment: okay, I'm going to put this into a bigger box, cuz I think it needs some formating too, sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can check where the php cli is running from with the `whereis` command, you can do the same for the composer too. The where is command returns with the paths of the scripts.

So when you say `whereis php`, you will see something like this as response:

```
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/share/php /usr/local/php7/bin/php
```

If you wanna use the php 7.4.5, then you should just figure out, where the path of the php 7.4.5 is located. For that you can ssh into the machine cd to the home directory and execute `whereis php`. Then you get a location what you can use with the other command too.

Now we need to know where the composer is running from:

```
whereis composer
composer: /usr/bin/composer
```

Finally we can execute the desired command, which is one of the path of the php script and the path of the composer script. For example:

```
/usr/bin/php /usr/bin/composer
   ______
  / ____/___  ____ ___  ____  ____  ________  _____
 / /   / __ \/ __ `__ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ _ \/ ___/
/ /___/ /_/ / / / / / / /_/ / /_/ (__  )  __/ /
\____/\____/_/ /_/ /_/ .___/\____/____/\___/_/
                    /_/
Composer version 1.10.5 2020-04-10 11:44:22

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]
```

That's it.